# Ruby/Rails: Use `separator: '-'` instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Writing test for my project, and notice this warning it terminal when running rspec

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the separator argument as a positional
parameter is deprecated and will soon be removed. 
Use `separator: '-'` instead.
(called from add_link at /myapp/app/models/post.rb:37)
```

I have an action before save record, looks like

```
self.link = theme + '-' + Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)
```

And I've tried to find some information about this but I don't really don't understanding what this warning means.

** EDIT **

Well, I've changed for `"#{theme}-#{Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)}"` but it still gives me the same warning.

Than I decided to go other way and changed for `"#{theme}(#{date})"`. The `date` method look like:

```
date = [Time.now.day, Time.now.month, Time.now.year]
date = date.join('-')
date
```

But it still gives me an error.

I don't think it's really big problem, but still I want t figure out why is that happening.

** EDIT **

Figure it out, it must gem that I use cause that problem (the gem is called `the_string_to_slug`) I will do future research to fix this warning with gem or I'll try to find way to replace it.

Comment: Is that the whole warning?

Comment: @Stefan edited to see the whole warning

Comment: What does the code look like from your model throwing the warning? `/myapp/app/models/post.rb:37`

Comment: There is no warning in console, when starting sever. There is only warnings when running spec. Mb I misunderstood you question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deprecation was removed 10 days ago. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0189f4db6fe518de8909b66b7f30046bac52dedc

Probably one of gems use old format of `parameterize` method.

Comment: Yes, you right. It now must be gems author issue. I'll write to author to let him know that this problem is appears

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
parameterize("Donald E. Knuth", separator: '_') # => "donald_e_knuth"
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/5.0.0/ActiveSupport%2FInflector%3Aparameterize

Comment: When I do this `self.random_link = parameterize("#{theme} #{Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)}")` it gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method "parameterize" for #<Post:0x007f9297a36f48>` don't quite understand why

Comment: "#{theme}-#{Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)}".parameterize

Answer (score 0):

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the separator argument as a positional
>   parameter is deprecated and will soon be removed. 
>   Use `separator: '-'` instead.

This is telling you not to insert `-` directly into your string, but to pass the options hash or keyword argument `separator: '-'` to your method instead from line 37 of your Post model.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you give me an example? (how to use it)